# jquery $.ajax php side POST serialized form

Tags: jquery

Sorry in advance, I know there are a few discussions about this topic, I am just new to this and have exhausted myself trying to learn it, so I must ask.

problem: I want to send my data in form to php file, this is what I have on js side

after form validation..

```
else {      
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'entry.php',
        cache: false,
        data: $(".contact_form").serializeArray(),
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == "error") {
                $('.success_box').hide();
                $('.error_box').show();
            }
            else {
                $('#sname').val('');
                $('#email').val('');
                $('#title').val('');
                $('#message').val('');
                $('#photo1').val('');
                $('#photo2').val('');
                $('.error_box').hide();
                $('.success_box').show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

my html form has name and id's = sname email title message

I dont know if my javascript is currently sending the data to my php file because I don't know how to access these values on the php page? also since its a js/ajax request I believe I don't need a action for the html form, like I don't call my php file on the html, just on the js, please correct me if this is wrong.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP page would have something to this effect... I don't actually know what's in your form so I just assumed.

```
$sname=$_REQUEST['sname'];
$email=$_REQUEST['email'];
$title=$_REQUEST['title'];
$message=$_REQUEST['message'];
$photo1=$_REQUEST['photo1'];
$photo2=$_REQUEST['photo2'];
```

And then I don't know what you want to do with it but you'd pass it with a SQL statement if you're sending it to a database.

Comment: Im not sure whats wrong, but i don't think my php ever runs.  Ive done several tests and I believe the js never sending the info am i right?

Comment: the data is (form).serialize()

Comment: and the else is seting the values back to 0 not grabbing the value

Comment: Is this uploaded somewhere? You can check what is being sent by looking at your networking console in your browser (f12)

Answer (score 0):

Values POSTed to PHP should be available in the [`$_POST` superglobal](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php). Treat the information in there carefully, as nasty folk can send malicious fields/values.

Your browser should have a developer console which you can use to inspect the request that goes to your PHP script, in case you're having trouble doing it on the PHP end. In Firefox, install the Firebug extension. In Chrome, just hit <kbd>F12</kbd> and see the Network tab.

There's a StackOverflow discussion about dealing with user-provided data here: [what is a good method to sanitize the whole $_POST array in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645131/what-is-a-good-method-to-sanitize-the-whole-post-array-in-php)