# How to replace all instances that has letter "s" with number "5"

Tags: php

I created a form that the user can type first and last name. The result should be replace letter "s" with "5".

The form page code:

```
<form action="form.php" method="post">
First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

The result page code:

```
<?php 
    echo $_POST= str_replace("s","5",$_POST); 
?>
```

Comment: What's the problem?  Show input/output and what you expect.

Comment: Peek at what's going on with this `$_POST` variable using `var_dump()` ... it may become clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, try the following:

```
<?php
     $_POST = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
     $fullname = $_POST['firstname'] . ' ' . $_POST['lastname'];
     echo str_replace("s", "5", $fullname);
?>
```

Note that we have sanitized your `$_POST` array in case the user has input malicious values which could cause XSS attacks. See this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4861211/823549