# error on validating image file on php api

Tags: php, api

I'm developing an api on which it gets an image and resizes it into three sizes and zips it. I have some methods to validate the file, run the resizer class and its methods and finally give files as zip file and a link to download them. Now I have problem with content type validation and zipping. I searched a lot and I couldn't find any tutorial. I'd be thankful if you help me with my errors.

**rest.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'constants.php';

abstract class Rest
{
public array $request;
public array $errors = [];

public function __construct()
{
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST') {
        $this->throwError(REQUEST_METHODS_NOT_VALID, 'Request method is not valid.');
    }

    $this->request = $_FILES + $_POST;
    $fileName = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['image']['type'];

    $this->validateRequest($fileName);
    if (empty($this->errors)){
        $this->executeApi();
    }
    $this->response();
}

public abstract function validateRequest($request);

public abstract function executeApi();

public function validateParameters($fieldName, $value, $dataType, $required) {

}

public function throwError($code, $message) {
    header("content-type: application/json");
    $errorMsg = json_encode(['error'=>['status'=>$code, 'message'=>$message]]);
    echo $errorMsg;
    exit();
}

public function response() {
 //???
}
}
```

**api.php**

```
<?php
 require_once 'image-resizer.php';
 class Api extends Rest
{

public function validateRequest($request)
{
  //        if ($request !== 'image/jpeg') {
    if ($_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'] !== 'image/jpeg') {
        $this->throwError(REQUEST_CONTENT_TYPE_NOT_VALID, 'Request content type is not valid.');
        $errors = json_encode(array("message" => "Request content type is not valid.", "status" => false));
        echo $errors;
    }
    json_decode($request, true);
}

public function executeApi()
{
    $source = $this->request['image'];
    $resize = new Resizer();
    $resize->imageResizer($source);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[getimagesize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) is not to be used to validate a file as image

```
$imgsize = getimagesize($sourceFile);
$srcWidth = $imgsize[0];
$srcHeight = $imgsize[1];
$mime = $imgsize['mime'];
```

you can use: [fileinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php)

OR you may validate extension using [pathinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

```
$allowedExt = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'];
$ext = strtolower(pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
if (!in_array($ext, $allowedExt)) {
      return FALSE;
}

// filesize validation
if (filesize($tmpName) > MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
    
}
```

check more on [filesize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php)

Edit:
You may check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914750/how-to-zip-a-whole-folder-using-php) for zipping files with PHP

EDIT:

```
$this->request = $_FILES + $_POST; // this is insecure way to get the data
```

check $_POST data sanitization
[what is a good method to sanitize the whole $_POST array in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645131/what-is-a-good-method-to-sanitize-the-whole-post-array-in-php)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
So I add this in my validateRequest(), right?

Comment: Yes you can use it in that method, depends what type of validation does your requirement need, ( like- extension validation etc )

Comment: I want to validate whole request 
like size and type

Comment: added file-size validation, you can check extension for type